# Conjugates of radicals

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I am not sure if one exists but is there a conjugate of the following:

$$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5}$$

I attempted it many times but can't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "conjugate".  From the point of view of algebraic number theory, this expression has conjugates
$$\pm\sqrt3\pm\sqrt2\pm\sqrt5\ ,$$
where any combination of signs is possible.  So there are eight answers to your question (one of which is the given number itself).

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})=((\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^2-5)=(3+2-2\sqrt{6}-5)=2\sqrt{6}$$