# Rationalize a fraction using conjugates

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I need help rationalizing the following expression using a conjugate:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5}}$$

I have had no luck rationalizing this expression with a conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: Hint: If you multiply the denominator by $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}$ you get $2\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: In fact, you already asked the question. What is wrong with the answers that were given, namely it reduces to $\frac{\sqrt{6}\cdot(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})}{12}$? Why?

Comment: The question referred to in the previous comment is this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765372/conjugates-of-radicals

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply by the conjugate of the denominator.

So you would multiply it by:

$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}}{ \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}}$

This will give you:

$\dfrac{2\sqrt{30}+4\sqrt{3}+6\sqrt{2}}{24}$